# Adding properties of an Object together in a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, db2

I have an app that creates ContactList Objects and adds them to a Dictionary collection. My ContactList objects have a property called AggLabels which is a collection of AggregatedLabel objects containg Name and Count properties. What I am trying to do is change the "else" case of my code snippet so that before adding a new AggregatedLabel it will check whether the AggLabel.Name exists in the AggregatedLabel collection and if this is true it will not add the AggLabel.Name again. Instead it will add the value of AggLabel.Count (type int) to the existing AggregatedLabel object. So for an existing object, if the first Count value was 3 and the second value is 2 then the new Count value should be 5. In simple terms I want to have unique AggLabel Names and add together the Counts where the Names are the same. Hope that makes sense - would appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Code snippet**

```
Dictionary<int, ContactList> myContactDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ContactList>();

        using (DB2DataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CONTACT_LIST_ID"]);

                if (!myContactDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
                {

                    ContactList contactList = new ContactList();

                    contactList.ContactListID = id;
                    contactList.ContactListName = dr["CONTACT_LIST_NAME"].ToString();

                    //contactList.AggLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel>() { new AggregatedLabel() { Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(), Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"])}};

                    contactList.AggLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel>()
                {
                    new AggregatedLabel()
                    {
                        Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(),
                        Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"])
                    }


                };
                    myContactDictionary.Add(id, contactList);
                }
                else
                {
                    ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];
                    contactList.AggLabels.Add(
                        new AggregatedLabel()
                        {
                            Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(),
                            Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"])

                        }
                );


                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];
AggregateLabel existing = contactList.AggLabels.FirstOrDefault(
                              l => l.Name == dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString()
                          );
if (existing == null) { contactList.AggLabels.Add(
                            new AggregatedLabel() {
                                Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(),
                                Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"])
                            }
                        );
                      }
else { existing.Count += Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"]); }
```

Comment: One more thing - how would I then extract these Aggregated Labels and put them in a separate Observable collection?

Comment: Then you could mark it as answer. :) 
What do you mean by a separate collection? you could use a dictionary that uses the name as key and lists of AggregateNames as values.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions I can think of:

1) Use a dictionary instead of the collection of aggregated labels the same way you do it for the contact dictionary. When yout use the name as key and the count as value, you can use the ContainsKey-Method to check whether the label already exists.

```
contactList.AggLabels = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

...
    else
    {
        ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];

```
    if (contactList.AggLabels.ContainsKey(dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString()))
    {
        contactList.AggLabels[dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString()] += Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"]);
    }
    else
    {
        contactList.AggLabels.Add(dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"]));
    }
}
```

2) I you need to use the AggreagteLabel object you can use a loop to search throug all labels.

```
else
{
    bool flagAggLabelFound = false;
    ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];

    foreach(AggregateLabel aggLabel in contactList.AggLabels)
    {
        if(aggLabel.Name == dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString())
        {
            aggLabel.Count += Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"]);
            flagAggLabelFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!flagAggLabelFound)
    {
        contactList.AggLabels.Add(
                        new AggregatedLabel()
                        {
                            Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(),
                            Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"])

                        }
        );
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for that great explanation. One more thing - how would I then extract these Aggregated Labels and put them in a separate Observable collection?

Answer (score 0):

@extract these Aggregated Labels and put them in a separate Observable collection:

1) If you a Dictionary for storing the labels in the contact list, this should work:

```
ObservableCollection<AggregateLabel> copyOfAggregateLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregateLabel>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> aggLabel in aggregateLabels)
    {
        copyOfAggregateLabels.Add(
            new AggregatedLabel() {
                Name = aggLabel.Key,
                Count = aggLabel.Value
            }

        );
    }
```

2) If you use an ObservableCollection of AggregateLabels, you get an AggregateLable instead of a KeyValuePair in the loop. The rest works the same way.

First I thought of something like:

```
ObservableCollection<AggregateLabel> copyOfAggregateLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregateLabel>(aggregateLables);
```

But this way you get a new ObservableCollection, but the labels stored in the new collection are still referring to the same objects as the ones in the collection you copy.